# How to write the result of compiling to an output in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm compiling C codes in a windows batch file as follows:

```
set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
for /d /r %CODE_DIRS% %%d in (*src) do (
   cd %%~d
   gcc *.c -o program
   cd %CURRENT_DIR%
)
```

I need to write compiling errors in a compile.log file if there is any error. How should i do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works only if `gcc` uses the default `STDERR` for error output:

```
gcc 2>>logfile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I think,

```
set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
for /d /r %CODE_DIRS% %%d in (*src) do (
   cd %%~d
   gcc *.c -o program >> /path/where/you/want/the/result/compile.log
   cd %CURRENT_DIR%
)
```